# Html input image type comes under maplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, openlayers

Any suggestions on how to solve problem with html input( of type image),
It is used to display full screen of a div(that has id="map") on click  and back to normal if clicks again.
It works fine without adding the map, but when adds a map by calling a function init() on ready state it won't work, input type comes under the map

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/TXbBc/1/ . please comment the init() function call so that you can see that It works fine without adding the map.

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Comment: I've figured out the problem, Add map.updateSize(); to the end of $("#btn-full-screen").click function

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index

```
<input id="btn-full-screen" style="z-index:9999;" title="Full Screen" class="btn-full-screen" type="image" src="img/fullscreen-en.png" alt="settings"/>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/TXbBc/2/

Comment: It doesn't display full screen of map

Comment: what you mean by full screen? it is working similar to when the init() is commented out.

Comment: there is a violet color on the right side of the page, what i'm trying to do is display the map as full screen

Answer (score 0):

try setting your input button's `z-index` property

Answer (score 0):

Change your button css to this:

```
.btn-full-screen {
    background-color: Gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 3%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: You can check @Sandeep G B example , map doesn't fit into full screen

Comment: That is another problem which exists in your provided source as well. This solution does not change anything else just brings the button on top of other elements.